# How do you pair points on separate layers with similar attributes in Qgis?

Tags: qgis

I have two separate shape files with point data.  One is POI data and the other is exit location.  The poi data contains the unique exit id linking it to the exit.  How do I visually show this in qgis?  Some exits have multiple poi's some have none.

I've tried Points2one but it only links a few of them and it seems pretty limited.

Comment: How many points are we talking about here? Can you label the POIs with the exit number? Do you want to somehow differentiate them with symbology?  I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: You could create a straight line in another feature class (layer) but that would require some understanding of pyQGIS, avoiding obstructions between by bending the line is complex - something I'd not like to try in python... apart from that I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, can you clarify what you're trying to achieve here please.

Comment: Symbolize the POIs by Exit Number.  Put that into your legend.

Comment: It's 1400 poi points.  The exits have exit number, highway number, etc.  They are all across the US though so those repeat from state to state.  Each exit has a unique identifier that is also included in the poi information in order to link them.  I figured out how to get Points2One to work somewhat.  The points you want joined have to be sorted so they follow each other on the table.  I was able to get one line connecting all associated points however it would be better represented as a child/parent where each poi would have a line connecting to the exit it's associated with.

Answer (score 3):

Using **QGIS 3.0** `Geometry by expression` function (in `Vector geometry` group).

Please see a sample of two point layers (`POI` and `EXIT`).

Note that first three points in `POI` (id=*1, 2, 3*) are all linked to *Exit_DEF* in `EXIT` layer.

[image]

Activate **Geometry by expression** tool and select `POI` as `Input layer`, set `Output geometry type` to `Line`, then click on the big epsilon mark. Input an expression as below:

```
make_line($geometry, geometry(get_feature('EXIT', 'exit_name', "exit_id")))
```

[image]

Output would be a new `Modified geometry` layer:

[image]

Comment: Awesome.  This looks fairly simple.  I solved the problem but it was a one off thing and I don't even remember how I did it.  Thanks for the response though.